# $\int_0^1 x^{2n} \sqrt{1-x^2 +\alpha(1-x^4)}\: d x, \quad \mathrm{for} \: \alpha>0 \: \mathrm{and} \: n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to compute integral
\begin{equation}
I(n):=\int_0^1 x^{2n} \sqrt{1-x^2 +\alpha(1-x^4)}\: d x, \quad \mathrm{for} \: \alpha>0 
\: \mathrm{and} \: n \in \mathbb N.
\end{equation}
This integral can be done by Mathematica when I take $n \leq 11$. For example, when $n = 0$ the integral turns out to be
\begin{equation}
I(0) = \frac{\sqrt{\alpha +1}}{3 \alpha } \left((2 \alpha +1) K\left(\frac{1}{\alpha
   +1}-1\right)-E\left(\frac{1}{\alpha +1}-1\right)\right),
\end{equation}
where $K(x)$ and $E(x)$ are the complete elliptic integrals of the first kind and second kind, respectively. Similarly, when $n=2$ Mathematica gives
\begin{equation}
I(1) = \frac{\sqrt{\alpha +1}}{15
   \alpha ^2} \left(-(\alpha  (6 \alpha +7)+2) K\left(\frac{1}{\alpha +1}-1\right) +(6 \alpha  (\alpha +1)+2) E\left(\frac{1}{\alpha
   +1}-1\right)\right).
\end{equation}
When I increase $n$ I find that Mathematica again gives the linear combinations of these two elliptic integrals. Therefore I guess that $I(n)$ should be the form
\begin{equation}
I(n) = A(n) K\left(\frac{1}{\alpha +1}-1\right) + B(n) E\left(\frac{1}{\alpha
   +1}-1\right).
\end{equation}
I find that Mathematica cannot give a result if I take $n>12$. Is it possible to compute this integral for arbitrary $n$? Or equivalently, is it possible to determine the coefficients $A(n)$ and $B(n)$ for arbitrary $n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a general simpler formulation
$$I_n=\frac{\sqrt{(\alpha +1)\pi} }4 \,\,\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(n+2)}\,\,\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},n+\frac{1}{2};n+2;-\frac{\alpha}{\alpha +1}\right)$$

$$I_n=\frac{\sqrt{a+1}}{8}  \Gamma (n+2)\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \frac{\Gamma \left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma
   \left(k+n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (k+1) \Gamma (k+n+2)}\left(\frac{\alpha }{\alpha +1}\right)^k$$

Using this formula, there is no problem for the generation in terms of elliptic integrals (I computed $I_{50}$ instantly).

Now, what are the polynomials, that is the question.